# How do I replace everything in a view upon a button press in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans

I'm fairly new to NetBeans, and I'm not quite sure where to start in figuring this out. I've started a project, designed this (below), and added code to the "Login" button that queries the database to see if the user's credentials are valid.

[image]

How, in NetBeans, do I then blow all that away and replace the window's contents with the main application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Login button clickHandler call `setvisible(false)` and create the object of your main application's view and then call `setVisible(true)` on it(main application object)

Comment: So I should create each "screen", if you will, as an individual object, and switch between them using setvisible()?

Comment: More specifically, I should right click on the project and select New > jFrame Form..., then use setVisible(). Thanks!